# How to find nearest pair of number to given pair of number?

Tags: javascript

I have one array of objects which have pair of numbers and i have one given pair

```
let points = [{x:20,y:30}, {x:34,y:40}, {x:45,y:30}, {x:55,y:30}]

let givenNumber= {x:19,y:25}
```

How i can find nearest pair from array which is near to my given pair number

Anyone can help?

Comment: First, the code is invalid so it will be an error

Comment: And when you fix it to be arrays, loop over and calculate the difference

Comment: You can sort the points array using a custom sort function (which calculates how near it is to your given point). Then take the first element of the array.

Comment: That's a loop and some geometry/math. Nothing that would prevent you from  at least a first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the distance and then reduce the array by taking the smaler distance of two points of the array.

```js
const distance = (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2);

let points = [{ x: 20, y: 30 }, { x: 34, y: 40 }, { x: 45, y: 30 }, { x: 55, y: 30 }],
    point = { x: 19, y: 25} ,
    result = points.reduce((a, b) => distance(a, point) < distance(b, point) ? a : b);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: 1) you can skip sqrt since it's monotonic. sqrt is one of the more expensive simple math operators. 2) you're recomputing distance for the same set of points multiple times.

Comment: That's some homework that doesn't show any research effort or any attempts at all. Not even an empty loop...

Comment: @junvar, i know, but then it's not *distance* anymore.

Comment: what if i have two pair like {100,2} and another if {2,100} and my given number is {99,4}, any idea?

Comment: what do you want in this case?

Comment: i want {100,2} in that case, like if you use these co-ordinates in svg then {100,2} and {2, 100} both points are not near to each other

Comment: @georg, thanks for changing the operator from bitwise XOR to power.